# Stencil buffer (буфер трафарета) и обводка вокруг объектов

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, opengl

Есть ощущение, что я не до конца понимаю как правильно работать с буфером трафарета в OpenGL.

**Итак, в чем суть:**

В OpenGL, наряду с z-буфером есть еще и буфер трафарета, который позволяет задать какие пиксели должны быть отброшены, а какие нет. При помощи данной штуки обычно делают различные обводки вокруг объектов. Я также решил использовать эту возможность для этого. Алгоритм следующий:

- Рисуем объект, при этом записывая в буфер трафарета единицы для каждого пикселя этого объекта
- Чуток увеличиваем объект (чтобы он был чуть больше предыдущего варианта)
- Функцию трафарета настраиваем таким образом, чтобы тест проходили только те пиксели, для которых в буфере трафарета значение не равно единице
- Снова рисуем объект, однотонным цветом (уже увеличенный) и в итоге получаем рамку этого цвета вокруг исходного объекта.

**Так это выглядит в коде:**

В начале, при инициализации рендерара, делаю вот это. Таким образом я устанавливаю поведение - что делать со значением трафарета если не пройден тест трафарета, если не пройден тест глубины, если пройден тест глубины (у меня получается что значение будет обновлено только в случае прохода теста глубины и теста трафарета)

```
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
```

Затем, в самом цикле отрисовки объектов, я делаю так

```
// о б ъ е к т

// Тест будет пройден в любом случае (какое бы значение не было в буфере)
// После прохождения теста в буфер будет внесено значение 1 (поведение из glStencilOp)
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);

// Матрица модели
glm::mat4 mdodelMatrix = light->getModelMatrix();
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(solidColorShaderID, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mdodelMatrix));

// Передать цвет
glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(solidColorShaderID, "lightColor"), 1, glm::value_ptr(light->color));

// Привязать VAO
glBindVertexArray(this->defaultGeometry_.cube->getVaoId());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->defaultGeometry_.cube->getIndexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
glBindVertexArray(0);

// о б в о д к а

// Тест считается пройденным если в буфере не 1
// После прохождения теста в буфер будет внесено значение 1 (поведение из glStencilOp)
glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 0xFF);

// Матрица модели (чуть увеличенный вариант)
mdodelMatrix = light->getModelMatrix(1.1f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(solidColorShaderID, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mdodelMatrix));

// Передать цвет
glm::vec3 col = {1.0f,0.68f,0.0f};
glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(solidColorShaderID, "lightColor"), 1, glm::value_ptr(col));

// Привязать VAO
glBindVertexArray(this->defaultGeometry_.cube->getVaoId());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->defaultGeometry_.cube->getIndexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

В итоге я получаю вот такой результат:
[image: Рамка сливается с рамкой другого объекта]

То есть обводки объектов сливаются. Я бы хотел добиться иного эффекта, чтобы обводка рисовалась поверх других объектов. Как я понимаю, это происходит из-за того, что при рисовании исходного объекта, в буфер трафарета всегда добавляются единицы (даже если z-тест не был пройден), поскольку я делаю перед рисованием исходного объекта следующее:

```
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
```

Но с другой стороны, я ведь указал, что если тест глубины не пройден, то никакой записи не происходит

```
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
```

Так почему же тогда он все равно пишет в трафарет, игнорируя это правило? Это из-за GL_ALWAYS? А как тогда настроить таким образом, чтобы он писал в трафарет только в том случае если пройден z-тест а не в любом случае? Сколько я не пытался делать разнообразные вариации настроек, все никак не удавалось получить желаемый вариант. Очень любопытно, как подобное можно реализовать. За ранее спасибо.